# iconCls in a button text alignment - EXTJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4, alignment

```
var btnLogin = new Ext.Button({
             text: 'Login',
             scale   : 'large',
             width : 100,
             iconCls: 'checkicon',
             iconAlign: "right",

             handler: function(){
               if(Ext.getCmp('username').getValue() !== '' && Ext.getCmp('password').getValue() !== ''){
                 loginForm.getForm().submit({
                   url: 'authenticate.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   params: {
                     response: hex_md5(Ext.getCmp('challenge').getValue()+hex_md5(Ext.getCmp('password').getValue()))
                   },
                   success: function(){
                     window.location = 'tabs-adv.html';
                   },
                   failure: function(form, action){
                     Ext.MessageBox.show({
                       title: 'Error',
                       msg: action.result.message,
                       buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                       icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
                     });
                   }
                 });
               }else{
                 Ext.MessageBox.show({
                   title: 'Error',
                   msg: 'Please enter user name and password',
                   buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                   icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
                 });
               }
             }
           })
```

[image]

### Question

The `Login` and the check icon gap are too much, how to let the check icon and the Login text stick together,or let the iconCls align to left abit.

### UPDATE

```
.checkicon {
    margin-right: 25px;
    background-image:url(../images/CheckIcon.png) !important;
}
```

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky because the button icons are absolutely positioned within the button. You can try something like this in your .checkicon class:

```
.checkicon {
    right: -25px !important
    background-image:url(../images/CheckIcon.png) !important;
}
```

This should achieve the same effect that you are looking for with margin-right.

Answer (score 0):

Try not setting your scale to large and remove the width. It should automatically take the right amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `margin-right` property to the **checkicon** CSS class, with a value you choose, 15px for example. This way, your button width will keep the same, and only the space between the text and the icon will be reduced.

Comment: `.checkicon {
 margin-right: 25px;
    background-image:url(../images/CheckIcon.png) !important;
}` can't work.nothing happen after setting here

Comment: ya,i have tried to add `!important` to `margin-right`,but still can't work